# "Stacking" (Ensemble) Models in R - Zero Training Error?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, xgboost, ensemble-learning

As a learning exercise, I am trying to manually write the code (in R) for "stacking" (ensemble) different machine learning models together (the goal is binary response classification). I have taken the popular "sonar" dataset from R : I first take some training data and feed it to the "random forest" algorithm as well as the "ada boost" algorithm. I take the output probabilities from both of these algorithms, and then feed it to the "xgboost" algorithm for the final prediction. For some reason, this is resulting in a model with 0 training error. This can not be right.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and how can I fix this problem? I have attached my code below.

```
library (mlbench)
library (randomForest)
library(ada)
library(xgboost)
library(caret)
```

data(Sonar)

```
     index = createDataPartition(y=Sonar$Class, p=0.75, list=FALSE)
     train_set = Sonar[index,]
     test_set = Sonar[-index,]
    
    ########Fit Random Forest
    model_rf = randomForest(Class~., train_set, mtry = 12, ntree=500, prob=TRUE)
    model_rf
    
    ####### Fit ada model
    model_ada = ada(train_set[,-61],train_set$Class, nu=0.01, iter = 100, type="discrete")
    model_ada
    
    ######### Predict on train data
    
    pred_train_rf = predict(model_rf,train_set[,-61], type="prob")
    pred_train_ada = predict(model_ada,train_set[,-61], type="prob")
    
    ######### Append predicted probabilities to the trainset : for class "M"
    
    train_set$pred_rf = pred_train_rf[,1]
    train_set$pred_ada = pred_train_ada[,1]
    
    ############# Fit xgboost model on the predicted probabilities of earlier two models
    
    data_matrix <- as.matrix(train_set[,c(62:63)])
    output_vector = as.vector(ifelse(train_set$Class == "M",1,0))
    
    model_xgboost <- xgboost(data = data_matrix, label = output_vector, max.depth = 2,
                    eta = 1, nthread = 2, nrounds = 10,objective = "binary:logistic")
    
    ######################################### 
    [1] train-error:0.000000 
    [2] train-error:0.000000 
    [3] train-error:0.000000 
    [4] train-error:0.000000 
    [5] train-error:0.000000 
    [6] train-error:0.000000 
    [7] train-error:0.000000 
    [8] train-error:0.000000 
    [9] train-error:0.000000 
    [10]    train-error:0.000000
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour here is unexpected. RandomForest is always overfitted to the training data.

You can see this by working out the accuracy of the RF model on the training data.

```
model_rf = randomForest(Class~., train_set, mtry = 12, ntree=500, prob=TRUE)
mean(predict(model_rf, data = train_set) == train_set$Class)
```

Almost everytime you run your code this is 100% accurate. So, if I am correct you are more or less using Class to predict Class in your xgboost code.

What you need to do is change the workflow a bit. Instead of using the training data for `data_matrix`, use the test_data. That should do the job. You'll also need to write a loop and do this a large number of times to get a more realistic idea of predictability as the small dataset likely results in a lot of noise in any accuracy measures.